# iFrames get cut off in IE8, full height in all other browsers

Tags: iframe, browser, internet-explorer-8, height, frame

My clients insist on using IE8, which means everything has to be IE8 compatible. We have iFrames on a couple pages, and they're getting cut off in IE8. This is how the page looks in IE9:

[image]

(the form extends even further down the page, this is just as much as I could get in a screen capture)

but in IE8 it gets cut off, seemingly at the height of the window:

[image]

Does anyone know why IE8 is cutting it off like this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you produce a standalone demo that shows the issue?

Comment: www.chkd.org/Our-Services/Rehabilitative-Services-and-Therapy/Requests/Observation-Hours-Request-Form/ If you go to this page in IE8 you should be able to see the issue.

Comment: That URL redirects to /Error. Perhaps it's only for authenticated users?

Comment: sorry, try this. it's a public URL, you shouldn't need to be authenticated

https://www.chkd.org/Our-Services/Rehabilitative-Services-and-Therapy/Requests/Observation-Hours-Request-Form/